# C# Order of Operations Syntax Explanation

Tags: c#, .net, syntax

In a code review of a component library, I found syntax where some calculations for days per month are needed.

The simplified syntax is something like:

```
int preDays = (new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 })[3] - 2;
```

Where `[3]` and `-2` are variables. In the above example, the result of `preDays` is 1.

Could somebody please explain how we come to this result?

Comment: what don't you understand, specifically? it just creates an array gets the fourth element and substracts 2 from it.

Comment: `(new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 })[n]` will always be `n` for `0 <= n < 7`, and an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` otherwise. This code is... *suboptimal* at best.

Comment: It seems SO is a fearsome place to ask a question!

Comment: @MohsenHeydari don't feel bad...most of them simply forget what it's like to be a newbie in software development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Break down the code into its individual pieces. Just like in math, we perform operations inside the parenthesis first, so you're creating an array of integers with the values 0 through 6. Next, the code looks at index 3 (arrays in C# are 0-based). The value at index 3 is 3. Lastly, we subtract 2 from 3 to get 1 and assign it to preDays.

You can think of it like this:

```
int[] myArray = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
int myValue = myArray[3]; // Value is 3
int preDays = myValue - 2; // Value is 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was just messed it with defining a two dimensional array.

Answer (score 1):

you are creating an array an making an  arithmetic calculation on the same line and given  that
index  in c# `has a zero as base`  so if you  count `0,1,2,3`  you will get a value 3 in  the 4 case of the array so  `3 minus 2` you will  get 1

So  take it like that

```
var myArray = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
int myValue = array[3]; //3
int preDays = value - 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this help:

```
var array = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
int value = array[3]; //3
int preDays = value - 2; //1
```

Answer (score 1):

This one's quite easy in my opinion:

within the () there's a new anonymous array defined. An array which consists of seven elements being 0,1,2,3,4,5 and 6. From this array you take the 4th element.
([3] refers to the fourth element as counting starts from [0] referring to the first element).

The fourth element of the array is 3, so the expression `(new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 })[3]` resolves to 3. Subtracting 2 from 3 makes preDays to be filled with 1.

Answer (score 1):

In `int preDays = (new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 })[3] - 2;`

`(new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 })` will create temporary integer array of size 7 and with values(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6).

`(new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 })[3]` will extract 4th item(item with index 3) i.e value 3.

`(new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 })[3] - 2` will perform 3 - 2 = 1.